# Does bind-once in Angular cause problems when elements are added/removed from a collection?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I'm populating a table with a collection. Since I'm just displaying text I don't need Angular to put watches on everything I populate the table with and I use bind once. What happens when I update my collection by adding/removing elements? Does bind once prevent angular from evaluating newly added elements? Are there any pitfalls I need to be aware of?

Example: Will isDeleteable be evaluated for newly added elements?

```
<table>
     <tr ng-repeat="myElement in myCollection">
          <td>{{ ::myElement.Title }}</td>
          <td>{{ ::myElement.UploadedDate }}</td>
          <td ng-if="::isDeleteable(myElement)"><button type="button" ng-click="deleteElement(myElement)">Delete</button></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work fine, angular will always watch myCollection.

And what you've done is a good practice :)